# Sum of Power of Two Fibonacci reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Evaluate $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_{2^n}} \;.$$

I'm thinking of using a relation from a term to another.

Comment: It's the Millin series http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillinSeries.html. Here you can find a proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Millin_Series.

Comment: [Relevant](https://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/27/156929.html?1399274757) (only gets relevant halfway down though). Specifically, the one by amwmath, with the time stamp "Posted on Sunday, 04 May, 2014 - 05:33 am:".

Comment: And the very next comment there is relevant, too: "All right, now that we have both proved it, in our own separate ways, let's look online and find [eleven more](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-3/hoggatt2.pdf)." (By the way, a few comments up, Superbus finds a formula for the partial sum.)

Answer (score 1):

This series is known as the [Millin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillinSeries.html). [One can show that](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Millin_Series), $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{F_{2^n}}=\frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ by first proving, using induction, that: $$\sum_{n=0}^\ell \frac{1}{F_{2^n}}=3-\frac{F_{2^\ell-1}}{F_{2^\ell}},$$ and then taking the limit as $\ell\to\infty$, knowing that $\lim\limits_{\ell\to\infty}\dfrac{F_{\ell+1}}{F_\ell}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{F_{2^n}}=\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\left(3-\frac{F_{2^\ell-1}}{F_{2^\ell}}\right)=3-\dfrac{1}{(1+\sqrt{5})/2}=\dfrac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$